# Meteor cordova: Oauth error when build to apk

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs, meteor, meteor-cordova

Now I am developing an app with meteor cordova.
I used oauth2 for sign in with facebook, google, twiter but It's just working on webserver. When I build to apk for release, the oauth2 is error. So I cannot sign in.
Anyone can help me fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: More information please - what have you tried? Have you googled other people with the same problem?

Comment: when I run by "meteor run android-device --settings ..." -> It's work.
But when I buid to apk by "meteor build --server ... --mobile-settings ... -> It's error.
I search a alot but I didn't find any the same problem.